# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MachAr'?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I have a question. When I import 'variance_inflation_factor ' from 'statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence', I get ' module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MachAr'' error, what is the reason?

I once executed this code in a project and it worked without any problems, but it gives this error for subsequent projects

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue while running `import statsmodels.api as sm`. The issue was happening with `numpy==1.24.2`. Downgrading it to `1.23` solved the issue for me. I have not tested newer versions tbh, so another one might work as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Databricks. The issue arose when I upgraded Numpy to 1.24.5. Before that, the code was working fine. So I needed to downgrade to 1.23 to resolve the issue. It worked for me.

```
pip install Numpy==1.23.5
```

Answer (score 3):

`MachAr` was deprecated in the [numpy v1.22](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.22.0-notes.html#the-np-machar-class-has-been-deprecated) release notes.
Rather than holding back numpy to an older version, you could also use statsmodels v0.13.1 or newer.  That was the version that fixed this issue.